# (Rust) Is there a way to auto-borrow for overloaded operators?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a basic Polynomial type in Rust, with overloaded operators for the math operations. So far, I could manage to implement the basic operations like addition, subtraction, etc. by overloading the operators. The problem is, I would like to take operands by reference to avoid unnecessary copies. Ie. :

```
impl ops::Add for &Polynomial {
    type Output = Polynomial;
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Polynomial {
        let mut result = self.clone();
        for (power, coeff) in other.coefficients.iter().enumerate() {
            result.add_coeff(power, *coeff);
        }
        result
    }
}
impl ops::Sub for &Polynomial {
    //  Implementation
    //  ...
}
impl ops::Mul for &Polynomial {
    //  Implementation
    //  ...
}
//  Etc.
```

This works as expected, however it forces the user to borrow the operands explicitly each time, which becomes less readable as the expressions become more complex :

```
let (quotient, remainder) = p2.div_rem(&p1);

assert_eq!(&(&quotient * &p1) + &remainder, p2);

//  Even worse example found on the internet.
//  Note that you need to explicitly borrow each and every intermediate result :
let result = &(&(&a * &b) + &(&c * &d)) / 2;
```

Instead of the last two lines, I think it would be much cleaner and readable if I could just write :

```
assert_eq!(quotient * p1 + remainder, p2);

let result = (a * b + c * d) / 2;
```

…and let the borrow happen « automatically » (just like it does when you call a method which has a `&self` as its first parameter on any value : it is automatically and implicitly borrowed without having to explicitly borrow it).

However I don’t know if it is possible to do, or how ?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, no, there's no easy way of doing this because Rust references are always explicit, never implicit, due to both design choices (i.e. avoid the same design issues of C++ references, which are *weird*) and necessity (due to the borrow checker).

`T, &T, &mut T, *const T`, ... are all different types *with different semantics*, so allowing `impl ops::Add for &Polynomial` to also work for `Polynomial` would basically mean that `impl ops::Add for &T` would implement automatically `ops::Add` for `T`, which could lead to very weird and potentially unsafe outcomes, especially if the opposite is also true. And what about `&mut`? Would `&mut T` automatically decay to `&`, and with what implications on the lifetime of the borrow itself?

Also, implementing `ops::Add` on non-`Copy` value types is quite weird, due to the operator then causing its operands to be moved in - which is definitely not what people expect most of the time when they use `+`.

Comment: Yep, this is one of those situations where the theoretical ideal ("I want `+` and `-` on `Polynomial`") comes crashing into the pragmatic ("But they're not `Copy` so it's weird"), and Rust, being a low level language, lands on the pragmatic side of this dichotomy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure I understand your last paragraph. When people add two values, ie `let c = a+b;` what they expect is that the values `a` and `b` will still be available after the operation, and not consumed (and so that you can use the same value twice in the same expression as well, ie `let c = a*a;`), but I don’t see why it would exclude non-copy types, if we could give the value to the operator by reference ? I was actually surprised when I saw that the common operators (ie. +, -, *, /, %) did not take references in the first place, for this exact reason.

Comment: *Also, implementing ops::Add on non-Copy value types is quite weird, due to the operator then causing its operands to be moved in - which is definitely not what people expect most of the time when they use +.*  - This is not true, bigint crates tend to implement both, and yes, `+` and `-` do move things. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7dbb416711012e4e0c4e887e85f0e842))

Comment: Note that [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html), which is non-`Copy`, implements `Add`, taking the LHS by value and the RHS by reference.

Comment: @user4815162342 implementing both doesn't change what I've said - it still makes it weird, because _usually_ people expect both operands to be still available after doing a sum or subtraction. In most people's minds they are not destructive operators, and they instinctively expect them to behave as if they were defined on references.

Comment: @Jor Rust is all about memory safety, performance and clarity. An argument of type `T` is always moved, and a nothing is usually _borrowed_ implicitly outside of `self` in method calls (which would be intolerably unergonomic, and it's very safe due to the self-contained nature of `self` in a method call).

Comment: @Jor the reason behind allowing by-value operations that move is that you now have maximum control over ownership of data. If Add takes a `T`, the values you get are always moved to the function and you can use them to build a new `T` or whatever. If it's defined on &T, you always know it will not modify anything, and so on.

Comment: *it still makes it weird* - I don't see anything weird in `foo + bar + baz` just working. If you want to keep using any of those, you can add `&` as necessary. The fact that existing bignum crates do so shows that other API authors reason the same way.

Comment: @user4815162342 the weirdness doesn't come from `foo + bar + baz`, but from the `+` consuming its operands, which may come as a surprise to some people.

Comment: It may be surprising, but for types that are not `Copy` (as bignums can't be), one has to choose between `a + b + c` not working and `+` consuming its operands (when called without explicit borrow). Virtually all bignum crates choose the latter, there is nothing weird about it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to define arithmetic operations for both references and values. This can be a bit tedious for the implementation (and typically involves macros to cut down on code duplication), but provides maximum usability for the API user.

The user can then write regular-looking code without the extra borrows, but can also choose to borrow when they want to hold on to the value for later use (and thus avoid the needless copy). For example, with the `num_bigint` crate, all of these work:

```
    assert!(BigUint::from(1u8) + BigUint::from(1u8) == BigUint::from(2u8));
    assert!(&BigUint::from(1u8) + &BigUint::from(1u8) == BigUint::from(2u8));
    assert!(BigUint::from(1u8) + &BigUint::from(1u8) == BigUint::from(2u8));
    assert!(&BigUint::from(1u8) + BigUint::from(1u8) == BigUint::from(2u8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get much of the way there with [`std::borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html), which allows you to implement an operator when the right operator is either a borrow or move. This works because `Borrow<T>` features a blanket implementation for `&T` that effectively does nothing. Unfortunately, you can't `impl` a trait for another trait. So you need an `impl` for the cases where the left operator is a borrow and a move:

```rust
impl <Rhs> std::ops::Add<Rhs> for Polynomial
where
    Rhs: std::borrow::Borrow<Polynomial>
{
    type Output = Polynomial;

    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output {
        // Just call the other impl by borrowing self.
        &self + rhs
    }
}

impl <Rhs> std::ops::Add<Rhs> for &Polynomial
where
    Rhs: std::borrow::Borrow<Polynomial>
{
    type Output = Polynomial;

    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output {
        let rhs = rhs.borrow();

        // Now both self and rhs are &Polynomial. Implement add.
    }
}
```

Comment: You could certainly write a macro for this.